# .remove() method is removing words from another variable?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of strings `text`

```
text =  ["this","is","a","string","identifier","identifier","identifier","identifier","identifier","identifier","identifier","identifier","please","help"]
```

I want to get rid of **some** of the duplicates in this list, not all. So for example in the list above there are 8 instances of the word "identifier", I want to get rid of all but 2 of these instances *while leaving the original instances in the same position*; for example, the desired output would be

```
text = ["this","is","a","string","identifier","identifier","please","help"]
```

I have a list of strings of the duplicates I want to get rid of, stored in the variable `delete_words`

```
delete_words = ["identifier"]
```

To do this, I have:

```
from collections import Counter
temp_text = text # set up a static temporary variable so indexing issues don't arise
for word in temp_text:
    # keep count of words in _text_
    temp_word_counter_dict = dict(Counter([word for word in text]))
    if word in delete_words and temp_word_counter_dict[word] > 2:
        text.remove(word)
```

The problem with the code above is that

1. The for loop doesn't iterate through every word, it only iterates through the first 10 words, so the resulting `text` variable still has 4 instances of the word "identifier" rather than 2
2. For some reason I can't understand, the temporary variable `temp_text` is having it's words removed as well even though I specify `text.remove(word)`, so I have no idea what is going on here.

Can anyone advise on how I can delete the duplicate words from the list while leaving 2 dupes in their original position? Thanks

Comment: `temp_text = text` doesn't make a copy. It says that they're literally the same list. Any changes to one will affect the other. Look up how to make a copy.

Comment: Try either `temp_text = text[:]` or `temp_text = list(text)`

Comment: thanks... that was the problem. Didn't know that a copy wasn't set up when I declared it like that. thanks!